# Can't limit Postgres user access

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to automate creating databases and users in Postgres.

Currently, after I create the databases and users for each database, all users seem to have admin access and can do and see anything, including other databases.

Here is the SQL I'm running:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE MY_DB WITH ENCODING 'UTF8';
CREATE USER MY_DB_ADMIN WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE MY_DB TO MY_DB_ADMIN;
```

I'm relatively new to Postgres, so not sure if this is a Postgres nuance thing or SQL in general.

Thanks in advance

**Update 1**
By "do anything", I mean, I am able to perform selects, create tables etc in other databases.

I have now tried this:

```sql
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE MY_DB FROM MY_DB_ADMIN;
GRANT CREATE, CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE MY_DB TO MY_DB_ADMIN;
```

But this still doesn't work.
User **DB_ONE_ADMIN** is able to create tables in **DB_TWO**

Comment: That's Postgresql specific.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-overview.html, _If one PostgreSQL server cluster is planned to contain unrelated projects or users that should be, for the most part, unaware of each other, it is recommended to put them into separate databases and adjust authorizations and access controls accordingly._

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean with "see anything"?

Comment: The existence of a database is not considered privileged info in PostgreSQL.  Anyone who can log in to one database can see the names of all other databases.  As for "do and see anything", please be specific about what they can do and see.

Answer (score -1):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE MY_DB TO MY_DB_ADMIN;
```

The problem is with the last line here, you are granting all privileges on database MY_DB to MY_DB_ADMIN. You need to decide on the access levels for different users if this is something you don't want.

If restriction needs to be applied and current privilege needs to be revoked then use REVOKE command

Comment: But the user also gets access to other databases, not just the one in that line.  
It looks like GRANT ALL is too generic. I'll look into specific permissions

Comment: @Daxelarne tried that, still doesn't seem to work